Custom photo on microwave display
I have a wifi enabled GE Monogram Advantium microwave oven which has a color display screen. It loads photographs from the internet over Wifi using the Unsplash image service. I would like it to display my photos instead of the stock Unsplash photos from the internet.
I set up a WireShark session on my computer and had the oven connect to the internet through my computer (Wifi Bridge mode). I was able to see all TLS 1.2 encrypted requests to the USplash servers, but I am unable to decipher the URLs, requests, headers, responses etc.
I tried to set up Charles Proxy, but I was not able to see network flows, because my microwave does not allow my to configure a proxy server (I can only select Wifi Network). I also tried MITM but again was not able to capture any flows.
Finally, I tried to proxy all traffic from my Wifi bridge computer to another computer, but I was still not able to capture the traffic from the microwave on Charles proxy.
Does anyone have any other suggestions?

You need to set-up a transparent proxy and redirect the network traffic into the proxy, not only use bridged networking. How that is done depends on the OS. To my knowledge with Windows this is not possible.
For Linux it is documented in the Mitmproxy help: https://docs.mitmproxy.org/stable/howto-transparent/
Alternatively, you could try to use a non-bridged networking and announce your own DNS server like dnschef which allows you to send back your own DNS response and thus tell the oven that the IP of your PC is the one it is looking for. Then it will connect to your PC, instead of to the server. On the PC you need a proxy running in reverse-proxy mode (simulating a server).
However, no matter how you intercept the traffic, if the TLS/HTTPS implementation of the oven is correct then you won't be able to intercept the traffic, because that is the purpose of TLS. Without the ability to install the custom root-CA certificate of your proxy into the oven it won't accept intercepted TLS connections.
